# What is the status of the Lannisters after Season 8 Episode 5, "The Bells"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Tyrion is still alive at the end of Season 8 Episode 5, "The Bells", however,

> Both Jaime and Cersei died in this episode.

Is Tyrion now

> the last Lannister alive?

Comment: Not yet, there are probably some left somewhere between Castelly Rock and Kings Landing, e.g. occupying High Garden, but I don't think they have a bright future ahead of them.

Comment: @user1129682 - I have a feeling their future is bright, almost like a fire from above

Comment: @Reed yeah, the moment i clicked on Add Comment I was like "oh wait, bright most likely but too short to enjoy"

Comment: I am not completely convinced that Jaime and Cersei died in the collapse; it is still possible that one or both of them emerges from the rubble next week.

Comment: @Reed I hope you're not "Howland Reed", because that would be a cheap shot!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of the named Lannisters in the show the only remaining ones are Tyrion Lannister and Dorna Lannister, Kevan's wife. However, Dorna is a Lannister through marriage and Kevan is now dead so up to you if you count her and of course her true status is unknown.

There may be other Lannisters but we haven't seen them or been told about them in the show so per show canon it seems only these two are alive.

There is also the case of Tysha whom Tyrion married in his younger days. However, the marriage was essentially a sham as the Septon was drunk and Tysha was a whore who Jaime had paid to sleep with Tyrion. The marriage lasted two weeks until Tywin found out and sent her away. I think we can assume she isn't a Lannister per show canon but again it's up to you if you count her or not.

---

There is also the Lannisters of Lannisport who are a cadet branch of House Lannister. In the show we know of Reginald Lannister and his wife. Reginald was part of the Lannister forces, a captain during the War of the Five Kings but was sent home by Tywin for not doing a good enough job and making excuses. As far as we know he is still alive.

Comment: Tysha Lannister and Sansa Lannister maybe...?

Comment: Sansa's marriage probably doesn't count because it wasn't consummated and she still calls herself a Stark. Tysha is an edge case, probably worth adding.

Comment: Early seasons also mentioned `Lannisters of Lannisport`(cadet branch) quite often. So in any case house will survive.

Comment: @user28434 Good point forgot about them.

Comment: "However, the marriage was essentially a sham as the Septon was drunk and Tysha was a whore who Jaime had paid to sleep with Tyrion." Jaime later says that Tywin told him to tell Tyrion that.

Comment: @Acccumulation Does that happen in the show as well? I thought they skipped that bit but might not be remembering correctly.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I *think* it happens in the show, but it's possible I'm confusing it with the book. It's supposed to be the primary motivation for Tyrion visiting, and subsequently killing, Tywin after Jaime frees him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I checked the scene where Jaime frees Tyrion and it doesn't happen there so I think they might skip it.

Comment: I wonder where Tysha is?