# After the events of the final episode of *Game of Thrones*, who rules Casterly Rock now?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Now that Tyrion is no longer a fugitive of the Crown and as the most senior successor to be ruler of Casterly Rock, can he be head of House Lannister as well as being Hand of the King?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Lord Tywin was both Hand of the King _and_ Lord of Casterly Rock for some time during the reign of Joffrey, so I guess he can. There's the thing of his “lifelong punishment” though.

Comment: Eddard Stark was also Hand without renouncing his lordship over the North. I'm sure there are other examples of ruling nobles serving as Hand. (In fact, I'd be interested in an example of a Hand who *wasn't* already the head of a major house.)

Comment: @chepner Plenty of hands have been younger sons of great houses, some have even been lowborn and Septons. Chief examples being Ser Osmund Strong, Septon Murmison, Septon Barth, Ser Ryam Redwyne, Ser Otto Hightower, Ser Tyland Lannister, Brynden Rivers.

Comment: @Aegon the question is from 2 years ago with no answers given recently, my question relates to the last episode of the final season so related but not a dupe and certainly not answered

Comment: @Seamusthedog in this case, bounty the other one with the reason "looking for an updated answer". This is the proper way to do it, not re-ask it :)

Comment: The accepted answer on the dupe target has been consistently updated, and is current as of the series finale

Comment: @Seamusthedog See the spoilers for each season's developments at the end of the show part. Please let me know if you still feel it isn't a dupe

Comment: Can someone confirm the edits were made prior to my question? There is only one answer/edit from a very similar time and the rest are from 2016/17 ish

Comment: @Seamusthedog Since I made the edits, I'd say no they were made after I saw your question. That question did not come to my mind until I saw yours. _IF_ you knew about that older question, you can have asked the answerers for updated answers or started a bounty as Jenayah said. That doesn't make your question non-dupe.

Comment: If 2 more mark as dupe I will make it 4, still think it's related but not the same as both questions are based on 2 different era's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes Tyrion can be Lord of Casterly Rock and Hand of the King as Tywin Lannister, his father, had been before him. As Tyrion is the most senior member of House Lannister left alive, [see here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212424/58193), he would be Lord of Casterly Rock unless the King assigned it to someone else. Lacking any evidence this is the case we can assume Tyrion holds the position.